# Completion suggestions while typing

Tags: autocompletion

I use Vim a lot for writing tasks and I used ^p for completions. However, is there a plugin that suggests you completions while typing like in Andriod-smartphones ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By "suggests you completions" I assume you mean that the completion popup appears automatically without interrupting your typing. If so, yes, there are a number of them. To name two [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) and [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe).

You can use [VimAwesome](https://vimawesome.com/) to search for others. It has [an entire category](https://vimawesome.com/?q=tag:autocomplete) dedicated to "autocomplete", a super set of the type of plugin you're interested in. Included are [the two mentioned by Karl](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15002/completion-suggestions-while-typing#comment25712_15003) in the comments below: [nvim-completion-manager](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/nvim-completion-manager) and [deoplete](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/deoplete-nvim).

Comment: I think deoplete and nvim-completion-manager should also be mentioned here. I think both are modern and good alternative.

Comment: Yes,exactly what I have searched... Thank you very much for our prompt response.

Comment: @ScottFritzpatrick You're welcome. Good luck.