# Issues with autocomplete in vim8

Tags: vimscript, autocompletion

I have installed two vim plugins [`javacomplete2`](https://github.com/artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2) and [`vim-emoji`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-emoji) successfully but I'm not able to use their auto-prompting feature which enables the user to select an autocomplete suggestion without having to press any key.

In case of `javacomplete2`, I am able to use `SUPERTAB` alongside to fetch suggestions but that isn't satisfactory since it slows down my programming let alone make it faster. And there are no suggestions in case of `vim-emoji`.

I know that my `.vimrc` file is probably misconfigured, but since the documentation of these plugins is hard for a **vim-beginner** like me to understand. I'm reaching out to StackExchange for help.

My [`.vimrc`](https://github.com/UtkarshVerma/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc).

PS: I have ensured `echo &omnifunc` and `echo &completefunc`. tl;dr I want autocomplete suggestions while typing as in `YouCompleteMe` for both the plugins.

Comment: [:h ins-completion](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#ins-completion)

Comment: not much helpful. :(

Comment: Well, did you try the various key combinations? Most likely CTRL-X CTRL-U for user-defined completion and CTRL-X CTRL-O for omni completion.

Comment: I did and they work just fine, but it's a bit slow to keep pressing them every time for completion. I want the suggestions to pop up automatically while I'm typing without having to press anything.

Comment: For completion to popup while typing you'll need a plugin. See:  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/15002/completion-suggestions-while-typing/15003#15003

Comment: Adding those plugins fetches their completions, I want a plugin or command to fetch `javacomplete2` and `vim-emoji` completions since they are better.

Comment: The [`javacomplete2` repo](https://github.com/artur-shaik/vim-javacomplete2) shows a gif in which it is being done. I want to know how.

Comment: ask the plugin author :)

Comment: @Rich Supertab is working fine. It fetches completions on <Tab> press but what I'm looking for are completion suggestions without having to press any button. It should happen automatically while typing like it is in `YouCompleteMe` or `AutoComplPL`

Comment: Apologies. I misread. Deleting my comment for tidyness (and I'll delete this one too once you've had a chance to read it.)